# No data received - editAction Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.1

I have setup a module which includes a menu and grid in the backend to edit the entities. The index url, showing the grid overview of all of the entities works, but the new/edit actions are not working. I am receiving No data received (ERR_EMTPY_RESPONSE). I have tried clearing cache and different browsers, but neither have helped.

Here is the backend related code:
Controller index/new/edit actions:

```
class Badia_Siteseo_Adminhtml_SellingpointController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('websitedesign/sellingpoint')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Unique selling points'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Unique selling points'));
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();
}

public function newAction(){
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function editAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->load($id);

    if ($model->getId() || $id == 0){
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)){
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        Mage::register('sellingpoint_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('websitedesign/sellingpoint');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website design'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Webside design'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Unique selling point'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Unique selling point'));

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('badia_siteseo/adminhtml_sellingpoint_edit'))
                ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('badia_siteseo/adminhtml_sellingpoint_edit_tabs'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }else{
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('badia_siteseo')->__('Unique selling point does not exist'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
}
```

config.xml:

```
<config>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Badia_Siteseo before="Mage_Adminhtml">Badia_Siteseo_Adminhtml</Badia_Siteseo>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>     
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <badia_siteseo>
                <file>badia_siteseo.xml</file>
            </badia_siteseo>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml> 
</config>
```

badia_siteseo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <adminhtml_sellingpoint_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="badia_siteseo/adminhtml_sellingpoint" name="sellingpoint_grid" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sellingpoint_index>
</layout>
```

Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint:

```
<?php
class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sellingpoint';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'badia_siteseo';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->__('Unique selling points');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->__('Add unique selling point');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Grid:

```
<?php
class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'adminhtml/sellingpoint/edit', 
            array('id' => $row->getId())
        );
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Id'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('title', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Title'),
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'title'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('description', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Description'),
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'description'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Status'),
            'type' => 'options',
            'index' => 'status',
            'options' => $this->getEnabledStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('sortOrder', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Sort order'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'sortOrder',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('modifiedBy', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Modified by'),
            'type' => 'text',
            'index' => 'modifiedBy',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('modifiedDateTime', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Modified date and time'),
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'index' => 'modifiedDateTime',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('action', array(
            'header' => $this->translate('Action'),
            'width' => '50px',
            'type' => 'action',
            'actions' => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => $this->translate('Edit'),
                    'url' => array(
                        'base' => 'adminhtml/sellingpoint/edit',
                    ),
                    'field' => 'id'
                ),
            ),
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'id',
        ));
    }

    public function translate($args)
    {
        return Mage::helper('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->__($args);
    }

    private function getEnabledStatuses()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->getEnabledStatuses();
    }
}
```

Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit:

```
<?php
class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'badia_siteseo';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sellingpoint';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->__('Save unique selling point'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('badia_siteseo/sellingpoint')->__('Delete unique selling point'));

        $this->_addButton('saveandcontinue', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save and continue edit'),
            'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class' => 'save',
        ), -100);

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        $newOrEdit = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
            ? $this->__('Edit')
            : $this->__('New');
        return $newOrEdit . ' ' . $this->__('Unique Selling Point');
    }
}
```

Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit_Form:

```
class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', 
            array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
            )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit_Tabs:

```
class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('sellingpoint_tabs');
      $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
      $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('badia_sitesoe/sellingpoint')->__('Selling point'));
  }

  protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
      $this->addTab('form_section', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('badia_sitesoe/sellingpoint')->__('Selling point information'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('badia_sitesoe/sellingpoint')->__('Selling point information'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('badia_siteseo/adminhtml_sellingpoint_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));

      return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
}
```

Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit_Tab_Form:
This is not done yet, but I do not think that that would be reason that I am getting this error.

```
class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);

        $dataObj = new Varien_Object(
                array(
            'store_id' => '',
            'name_in_store' => '',
            'status_in_store' => '',
            'click_url_in_store' => '',
                )
        );
    return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that in the class Badia_Siteseo_Block_Adminhtml_Sellingpoint_Edit, the constructor method was protected instead of public.